# How to correct Invalid Protocol: null sending mail using javax.mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, nosuchproviderexception

i'm trying to send mail in this way:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.setProperty("mail.host", "out.alice.it");
props.setProperty("mail.user", "mymail@domain.it");
props.setProperty("mail.password", "*****");
Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("Host", "Name"));
```

On the row `Transport transport...` i retrieve this error:

```
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: Invalid protocol: null
    at javax.mail.Session.getProvider(Session.java:440)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:659)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:640)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:626)
    at Mail.sendMail(Mail.java:151)
```

How can i resolve? Can someone help me? Thanks!! :)

EDIT:

If i create a main and launch that method to send mail, it works good!
My problem borns after i read mail into mail folder:

```
Properties properties = System.getProperties();  
properties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");  
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
store.connect("pop3.domain.it", "mail@domain.it", "****");  
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");  
FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
Message messages[] = inbox.search(ft);
for(Message message:messages) {
   if(message.getFrom()[0].toString().equals("aMail")){
      sendMail(message.getFrom()[0].toString());//Error!
   }
}
```

I Thought the exception borns cause i've opened store to get inbox mail so i edit in this way:

```
ArrayList<String> reply = new ArrayList<String();
for(Message message:messages) {
    if(message.getFrom()[0].toString().equals("aMail")){
        reply.add(message.getFrom()[0].toString());
    }
}
store.close();
for(String mail : reply){
   sendMail(mail); // ERROR AGAIN!
}
```

very strange....

SOLVED IN THIS WAY:

i modified this row

```
Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
```

to

```
Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props);
```

Comment: Yeah, there is only one default `Session` instance.  If you try to get the default one after it's been fetched with a different authenticator, it'll fail with the error you saw.

Comment: For me the solution here worked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590762/javax-mail-nosuchproviderexception-invalid-protocol-null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might try another way:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "out.alice.it");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
final PasswordAuthentication auth = new PasswordAuthentication(smtpUser, stmpPassword);
Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { return auth; }
});
MimeMessage message = ....;
// compose the message
Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: it get me this exception :                    java.lang.SecurityException: Access to default session denied

Comment: I don't know why but when i send email via a main class it's not problem but when i send mail via jsf application it needs to set protocol smtp.

Comment: I use  Pavel's method it works fine when I run it from NetBeans but when build a wrapper using Launch4j the created windows exe fails with "failed to connect." What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this same error, and my problem was I forgot to include:

```
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
```